# Dydx API Error: Order expiration cannot be less than 1 minute(s) in the future

Tags: python, web3py

I am working with the Dydx API to close all positions using the `abort_all_positions` function. However, I encountered an error message that says:

> Error closing all positions: DydxApiError(status_code=400, response={'errors': [{'msg': 'Order expiration cannot be less than 1 minute(s) in the future'}]})

Here is the full code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from func_utils import format_number

# Place market order
def place_market_order(client, market, side, size, price, reduce_only):
    # Get position ID
    account_response = client.private.get_account()
    position_id = account_response.data["account"]["positionId"]

    # Get Expiration time
    server_time = client.public.get_time()
    expiration = datetime.fromisoformat(server_time.data["iso"].replace("Z", "")) + timedelta(seconds=60)

    placed_order = client.private.create_order(
        position_id=position_id,
        market=market,
        side=side,
        order_type="MARKET",
        post_only=False,
        size=size,
        price=price,
        limit_fee="0.015",
        expiration_epoch_seconds=expiration.timestamp(),
        time_in_force="FOK",
        reduce_only=reduce_only
    )

    # Return result
    return placed_order.data

# Abort all open positions
def abort_all_positions(client):

    # Cancel all orders
    client.private.cancel_all_orders()

    # Protect API
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Get markets for reference of tick size
    markets = client.public.get_markets().data

    # Protect API
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Get all open positions
    positions = client.private.get_positions(status="OPEN")
    all_positions = positions.data["positions"]

    # print(all_positions)

    # Handle Open positions
    close_orders = []
    if len(all_positions) > 0:

        # Loop through each position
        for position in all_positions:
            # Determine market
            market = position["market"]

            # Determine side
            side = "BUY"
            if position["side"] == "LONG":
                side = "SELL"

            # Get price
            price = float(position["entryPrice"])
            accept_price = price * 1.7 if side == "BUY" else price * 0.3
            tick_size = markets["markets"][market]["tickSize"]
            accept_price = format_number(accept_price, tick_size)

            # Place order to close
            order = place_market_order(
                client,
                market,
                side,
                position["sumOpen"],
                accept_price,
                True
            )

            # Append the result
            close_orders.append(order)

            # Protect API
            time.sleep(0.2)

        # Return closed orders
        return close_orders
```

Here is the `main.py`

```
from constants import ABORT_ALL_POSITIONS
from funct_connections import connect_dydx
from func_private import abort_all_positions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Connect to client
    try:
        print("Connecting to Client...")
        client = connect_dydx()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error connecting to client: ", e)
        exit(1)

    # Abort all positions
    if ABORT_ALL_POSITIONS:
        try:
            print("Closing all positions...")
            abort_all_positions(client)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error closing all positions: ", e)
            exit(1)
```

Has anyone else experienced this error with the Dydx API when closing positions? Could you please provide some insights or potential solutions to resolve this issue?

Comment: You're hacking the server time to eliminate the timezone.  The "Z" says it is in UTC, but by removing the Z, it's going to be interpreted as a local time.  However, you're not using `expiration` here, so perhaps that doesn't matter.

Comment: `fromisoformat` can handle the trailing "Z", and creates an object that knows it is UTC.  Why are you removing it?

Comment: @TimRoberts my mistake.  I'm still getting an error but this time it is, `Error closing all positions:  Invalid isoformat string: '2023-05-31T20:03:53.075Z'`

Comment: You're quite right, support for the 'Z' timezone was added in Python 3.11.  Earlier versions demand the numerical equivalent.  So, use `...replace('Z','+00:00')` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are taking the Udemy course and using this structure. I am a fellow student too and how I addressed this issue is exactly what Tim Roberts suggested. Simple replace `.replace("Z", "")` to `.replace('Z','+00:00')` and all positions should close properly.